# What does '^' mean in webpack module version?

Tags: webpack

I have webpack configuration like this:

```
"webpack": "4.33.0",
"webpack-cli": "3.3.5",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.1",
"webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
```

What does ^ symbol in the version string mean? Like what is the difference between "^5.34.1" and "5.34.1"?

Comment: @jonrsharpe. It is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ^4.2.1 the caret '^' means that it matches the most recent minor version (for the '2' here) for the specified major version (the '4' here).

It can match 4.3.1 by example, but not 5.0.0.